# Incrementally show images in sequence

Tags: java, android, while-loop, sequence, increment

This is a problem I have been having for a few days. I had no luck with a for loop so I am trying with a while.

What I want to to incrementally build a sequence of images that show themselves one at a time gaining one more to the sequence each time. The issue I am having is getting the images to print in sequence. I have 3 imageviews one image for each.

Lets say the array has two integers. when it's values are printed I want one image to show then the other. But what I get at the moment is they both would show at once.

```
    public void Show(){

    int i=0 ;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(3)+ 1 ;       
        list.add(rndInt);
        int totalElements = list.size();
     Log.d("LOOK", Integer.toString(rndInt));
     Log.i("VALUE LIST ", list.toString()+" <<<<LIST HERE");        

     while(i < totalElements) {      
        final CounterClass resetImage = new CounterClass(1000 , 0010);  
        retval =list.get(i);


        if  (retval==1){


            Centre.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash1);
            resetImage.start();
        }       
        else if (retval==2){


            upperRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash2);     
            resetImage.start();
        }   
        else if (retval==3){


            lowerRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.flash3);     
            resetImage.start();
}           
        i++;
            }
    }  
resetImage simply restores the image to it default after the period of time I desired has passed. 

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {  
                public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {  
                     super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);  
                }  
                @Override  // when timer is finished
               public void onFinish() {  
                    Centre.setImageResource(R.drawable.i1);
                    upperRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2);
                    lowerRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
                    lowerLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.i4);
                    upperLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.i5);  
               }
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }  }
```

How can each be shown one at a time. repeating the same sequence each time in order with the extra incremented value/image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you are not resetting the `list` anywhere. It is likely that you keep appending to it on every call, making the same image as before appear, plus all the next.

Edit: Here's an example:

Say you get 5 calls to show(), on each one you add a random number to the list. Say the random generator gives 2,3,3,1,2

```
call # - list
1      - 2
2      - 2,3 (both shown)
3      - 2,3,3 (same display, but 1 more iteration on the while)
4      - 2,3,3,1 (all 3 images shown)
5      - 2,3,3,1,2 (from this one onwards, always all 3 are show, but more and more spurious iterations happen)
```

If what you want if for images on the current list to blink for a short time, you need to adjust the timing, right now, the entire loop probably happens in 2-3 miliseconds.

---

Other tips:

1. No need to start the reset counter 3
2. A for(int i=0; i

--- Edit2 after clariffication of reqs:

I would build the entire thing differently.

1. First build the complete sequence, however long you want it. No need to do it little by little, we'll *show it* little by little.
2. Keep a counter of the `lastShown`, starting at 0.
3. Put a timer to call your method once per second or so.
4. On your method, reset all 3 slots, then turn on `slot[lastShown++]`

So, this will flash each element of the sequence once. If you want to show an empty sequence in between, you can always keep a separate boolean variable: `boolean showNow = true` and then on your method do `if(showNow)` and `showNow = !showNow`.

Comment: Well, sure, that's kinda my point, let me be more explicit in the answer.

Comment: thanks for the help. your example has summed up my issue totally. I don't understand what you mean about adjusting the timing. do you mean change the timing for  my resetImage?

Comment: No, I mean, you do want to "see" the images flipping trough the list right? To physically observe the sequence? I'm not completely clear on your final objective.